# mvc5 identity AllowAnonymous

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am trying to understand how [AllowAnonymous] tag works.

I have the following method

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Add()
{
    return View();
}
```

When I am not logged in, I am able to open this page.  I have been under the impression that I can do that only if I put [AllowAnonymous] tag above the method that I should be able to do that.  Is there a setting that I need to turn on to make this work?

Comment: [AllowAnonymous] is only relevant when you have you have Authorization activated, for example when the [Authorize]-filter is present.

Comment: @Nakata I tried add `[Authorize]` above it as well, but it had no effect.  How would I make this work?

Comment: How is your MVC application hosted? IIS with Windows Authentication, IIS Express with allowed Windows Authentication etc.?

Comment: @Alexei at the moment just localhost on a windows 7, but when deployed will be windows hosting on iis server

Comment: @ Bagzli Where are you placing the [Authorize] filter in that case? If you want to make your "Add()"-method anonymous you should place it above the class/controller wrapping the method.

Comment: @Nakata just above the `[HttpGet]` attribute

Comment: Yes, localhost, but there are several options: Developer Server, IIS Express, IIS 7 / 7.5? I am asking that because IIS / Express may be configured to use Windows Authentication which will automatically authorize you. Removing Windows Authentication and allowing anonymous authentication I think can be used to test if your functionality is really accessible to non-authenticated users.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[AllowAnonymous]` attribute is working only when you use `[Authorize]` attribute on a ***Controller*** level. For example, you use `[Authorize]` attribute on a `AccountController`. Also you want your users to be allowed for `Login` method without authentification. In this way you use `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on a `Login` method. In this case your users will be able to login to your site, because `[AllowAnonymous]` allows it

Does it make sense?

Comment: It should be noted that `[Authorize]` attribute can also be registered as a global filter, in which case `[AllowAnonymous]` works on the `Controller` and `Action` level.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you